# ArcGIS API - Creating Popups for Geoprocessing Result

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

With the ArcGIS API for Javascript I created a web application that accesses my before published geoprocessing service. The result of the service are a set of points and are displayed on the map. Here is the way how I display the points (symbol is a simple Marker Symbol):

```
var features = results[0].value.features;
for (var i=0; i<features.length; i++) 
{
  var feature = features[i];
  feature.setSymbol(symbol);
  map.graphics.add(feature);
}
```

Now I would like to enable popups for these points, which include some further attribute information that can be accessed with e.g. feature.attribute.name.

How can I, for these points, add a popup?

Comment: Which version of the Javascript Api are you using? For 4.0 beta you can find more info over here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html For 3.[n] you can find more info/samples over here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_extendInfowindow.html Cheers.

Comment: I use version 3.15. 
The problem is, that in all samples a layer is loaded, and then for the layer the infoTemplate is specified and the layer added to the map, like here: 

`var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/Street_Trees/FeatureServer/0",{
        infoTemplate: template,
        outFields: ["*"]
      });
      map.addLayer(featureLayer);`
 
But in my case, the result is an array of features, for which a graphic is created and added to the map. But I don't know how to specify the info window for these features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can do is add the graphics to a Graphic Layer. Then assign an InfoTemplate to that layer and add it to the map. Your code will look something like this:

```
var map = new Map({
        "basemap": "osm"
});

var template = new InfoTemplate();
      template.setTitle("<b>${qAddress}</b>");
      template.setContent("hello");
      template.setContent(getTextContent);

var graphicsLyr = new GraphicsLayer();
graphicsLyr.setInfoTemplate(template);
```

And in stead of adding the features directly to the map (like you did in your code example) you need to add them to the graphic layer. Like this:

`graphicsLyr.add(feature);`

finally add the graphicslayer to the map like this:

```
map.addLayer(graphicsLyr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked! 
Only thing: `graphicsLyr.graphics.add(feature);` did not work for me - but with `graphicsLyr.add(feature);` it works

Comment: I've updated the sample. Have fun with it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
One problem I face now is that my geoprocessing service is executed when the user clicks on the map. But of course it is also a click-event when the info window is clicked. It opens, but immediately the service is again executed. Do you maybe know how to work around this?

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround for this issue. You need to trigger the service in another way. For example with a button.

Comment: Ok, but the service requires an input location, which is given by the user through clicking on the map = setting a point. If I have a button for example, would it be possible in some way, that the user specifies the location (but not with hardcoded coordinates) ?

Comment: You can create a toggle button. When enabled users can click on the map and the service will fire. When disabled the service won't fire. In that way users can get popups without the service generating.

Comment: I will try this, thanks! Otherwise I thougt about opening the popup at mouse-over, I will see if it works.